# How to use firebase user property in nativescript

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, nativescript

How do you use firebase user property with Nativescript.
I have this in the Firebase console for the user property.
I am trying to send to device where eye_colour property is blue
[image]

In my nativescript angular component, I have initialised Firebase this way:

```html
firebase.init({
            showNotifications: true,
            showNotificationsWhenInForeground: true,
      
            onPushTokenReceivedCallback: (token) => {
              console.log('[Firebase] onPushTokenReceivedCallback:', { token });
            },
      
            onMessageReceivedCallback: (message: firebase.Message) => {
              console.log('[Firebase] onMessageReceivedCallback:', { message });
            }
          })
            .then(() => {
              console.log('[Firebase] Initialized');
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log('[Firebase] Initialize', { error });
            });
```

Then, I am not sure what is the next step. Any help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [analytics docs](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/ANALYTICS.md) in Firebase plugin repo.

**Sample Code**

```
firebase.analytics.setUserProperty({
    key: "origin",
    value: "demoapp"
  }).then(
      function () {
        console.log("Analytics user property set");
      }
  );
```